# Scroll Height of a child window using Windows API?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, user32

Does anyone know how to get the height of a scrollable child window using Windows API? I've found GetWindowRect but that appears to only return the RECT of the "visible" area but I want the RECT of the entire "scrollable" child window. This window is a 3rd party window so I would need to use, I'm assuming, the User32 WinAPI functions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you can do is to call [`GetScrollInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
SCROLLINFO si = {sizeof(SCROLLINFO), SIF_ALL};
GetScrollInfo(hWndChild, SB_VERT, &si);
```